# Instanceof with string name of class instead instantiating class

Tags: php, object, instanceof

Is it possible to proof if a class is an instance of a specific class without generating a new object?

At example I've got an array with class names:

```
$classNames = [
    'TestClass',
    'ExampleClass',
    'OtherClass'
];
```

Now I want to proof if these 3 classes are a instance of the main class (at example 'Classes').

In a loop it should proof like this:

```
foreach($classNames as $className)
{
   if($className instanceof Classes)
   {
      // some code
   }
}
```

But this isn't working because firstly I must instantiate the classes like `TestClass`...

Is there any alternative? I want to check if the classes in the array are a instance of 'Classes'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is_subclass_of`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) to make this check:

```
foreach($classNames as $className)
{
   if(is_subclass_of($className, 'Classes')
   {
      // some code
   }
}
```